# Web Service, JSON and Android. The result WS don't work correctly

Tags: android, json

i have this code:

```
    Carrera userRecived = null;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpGet httpget;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;
        /*Call Json service and Unserialize with Gson into the class*/
    try{
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        httpget = new HttpGet(Url); 

        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        entity = response.getEntity();

            String result= EntityUtils.toString(entity);        

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            userRecived = gson.fromJson(result, Carrera.class);


    }catch(Exception error){throw new Error("Error en el get -- "+error.toString());}
```

My problem is the next error:
03-08 19:07:42.899: E/AndroidRuntime(959): java.lang.Error: Error en el getcom.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting array but found object: com.jorgechu.circuitlacostera.Objetos.Carrera@405852d0

I waiting result from php webservice, the result may next JSON:

```
[{"Codigo":"1","Denominacion":"Popular de Xativa","Imagen":"1231313","Poblacion":"Xativa","Lugar":"Valencia","Fecha":"11 de Noviembre de 2012","Hora":"17:00","Descripcion":"para probar","Reglamento":"http:\/\/www.google.es","Kilometros":"21"}]
```

And I have a object Carrera where store this information.

I hope somepeople help me.
Thank you.

Comment: please put log for result and show is it correct or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
userRecived = gson.fromJson(result, Carrera.class);
```

to:

```
List<Carrera> userRecived = (List<Carrera>) gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<List<Carrera>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: I'm waiting a one result from Web Service. Is a 10 attributes represent one Object, no List. May be that result JSON is wrong?

Comment: It depends what your server is returning. I think your server is returning json array string

Comment: My server return this http://www.elblogdejorgechu.com/WSprueba.php. I want get atributes (i got this from query database, is one result (row) represent an object ) from web service to create a one object with android.

Comment: Yes, its an object encapsulated in an array format. You may simply get it from your **List<Carrera> userRecived** by using `Carrera item = userRecived.get(0);`

Answer (score 2):

Your are getting an array back, not an object.  So you have to do something like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection< Carrera >>(){}.getType();
List< Carrera > listOfObj= gson.fromJson(result, collectionType);
```

Comment: I'm waiting a one result from Web Service. Is a 10 attributes represent one Object, no List. May be that result JSON is wrong?